# Adding html content on multiple columns with just plain html and css?

Tags: html, css, templates, layout

I not sure whether this has been ask before but I can't seem to find the solution for this so far. If you take a look at the newspaper layout

http://inspirationhive.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Design-a-Grungy-Newspaper-Web-Layout-in-Photoshop-500x585.jpg

Take the 2columns for example (under 'HEADING EXAMPLE'), normally if there is text it will just filled up the first column but as the text grows it will continue expanding down the column......

My question is, will I be able to arrange the html and css in such a way that when the first column reaches a certain height and it will automatically continues in the second column?

The reason is because it will be quite flexible when it comes to creating a CMS template.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dividing a single div tag into 3 sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968548/dividing-a-single-div-tag-into-3-sections)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using

```
p {
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBUZJ/)

You can read more about this property at http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: Oh I didn't know css had this property, but it would be nice if they can atleast support IE9 though :P

Comment: @VincentChua don't forget to accept the answer! This is definitely the way to do it. For older browsers, you would have to use javascript. Some good libraries for this are: Masonry, Isotope and Packery.