# Dividing a single div tag into 3 sections

Tags: html, css

Essentially, what I want is sort of 3 sections on a page. There would be a div element with content in it. The problem is, making the div break into 3 pieces, sort of like a newspaper, where once the content reaches the bottom, it wraps around and goes into the next box.

No code, I haven't started yet.

Edit: I want to make columns

Comment: @elclanrs It's a simple question. If he had code, he would be done already. I don't think it's unreasonable here. He shouldn't have mentioned it though, as it sounds lazy.

Comment: div is a div, you can "divide" it in two by using float to float content inside (left and right).

Comment: @m59: I don't even understand the question TBH. Does he want to make columns?

Comment: @Vinh that's not really what he is looking for. I'm not sure if there's a css solution, but an intuitive name for it would be `line-width`. The text would go top to bottom but only a certain width, then start right of that top to bottom again.

Comment: @elclanrs I think so. I'm curious myself... All I could think to do would be to break it up into other elements, probably using javascript to calculate/automate the process.

Comment: Yes, but, it's one div, not many, and float left and float right are well and good for 2 divs, but not 4 or 5 or 6.

Comment: I give you an idea, use 3 div and javascript. when reach the end of the page, run javascript go get content in a div then push to your textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Columns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Example:

```
.columns-3 {
  column-count:3;
  -webkit-column-count:3;
  -moz-column-count:3;
}

<div class="columns-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
```

CSS columns are awesome! [I made a demo also (click).](http://jsbin.com/idEYITaZ/1/edit)

For older browsers, you would need javascript. Check out Masonry, Isotope and Packery.

Comment: It didn't work, while it does work on vthe mozzilla website, it doesn't work in my HTML document that I just threw together. (it consists of the html, doctype, head, body, and your example).

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that a moment ago, came here to update, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Use css `column-count` or `columns`.

IE 9 and older don't support the column-count property.

CSS:

```
.columns{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```

OR

```
.columns{
columns:3;
-webkit-columns:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-columns:3; /* Firefox */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```